# Cookie can not be set

Tags: php, symfony, cookies

I am using `name="_remember_me"` to set a cookie. The documentation of Symfony says:

> By giving the checkbox the name _remember_me (or the name you
>   configured using remember_me_parameter), the cookie will automatically
>   be set when the checkbox is checked and the user successfully logs in.
>   https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/remember_me.html

If I enable the checkbox, PHP tells me *["_remember_me"]=> bool(true)* but the cookie is still not set. I have checked it in Chrome -> Application -> Cookies but there is no cookie. I am using localhost.

[image]

Also I have checked `$request->cookies->all()` but it returns an empty array.

What exactly is the reason that my cookie cannot be set?

---

### Update

My *security.yaml* file looks like this:

```
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        in_memory: { memory: null }
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true
            form_login:
                remember_me: true
            remember_me:
                secret:   '%kernel.secret%'
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
                path:     /
                # by default, the feature is enabled by checking a
                # checkbox in the login form (see below), uncomment the
                # following line to always enable it.
                always_remember_me: true

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

*composer.json*

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.4",
        "symfony/asset": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/console": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.13",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.2",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "4.3.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "4.3.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What cookie did you look for? The default cookie name is `REMEMBERME`

Comment: @Barmar there are no cookies set. I have added an image to my question.

Comment: I think you need a `security.yaml` as described on the symfony page. You can't add an unknown option to a config file, `framework.session` in this case.

Comment: @A1rPun you are right. I have just installed security-bundle. Now I don't get any errors anymore but the cookie still can not be set.

Comment: It looks like there is noting wrong with your `security.yaml`. Strange, I want you to have those cookies ;). The only thing I can think of is providing your dependencies from `composer.json` so we can maybe spot a clue.

Comment: @A1rPun I have just updated my question, so that you see the content of my `composer.json` file. I hope that helps.